# How to plot a path from a set of instruction from a long string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just starting learning python 3 weeks ago and so far, I was mostly able to understand the information given in class. Now I'm really having trouble with this previous assignment for the past week now. While spending countless hours every day searching, reading, indexing the docs, GitHub, and other source material and trying it part of code. It's really hard when sometimes you just don't know what exactly you are looking for.

I still cannot figure out how to complete this program which is similar to what a turtle graphic would do.
But we aren't allowed to use the turtle module.

I need to basically create an algorithm to plot a path from a very long string of characters.
(Similar to turtle)

- A: Go forward by 1
- D: Turn right 90 Degrees
- G: Turn left 90 Degrees
- T: First encounter will stop the lining. The second encounter will reactive the lining.

The code must add a line from the initial position toward the new one. The initial starting position is
(x,y) for x = 0 ,y = 0

This is the string given.

AAAAADADAAGAAAAAAAGAADADAAAAADAAAAAAAAA TDDAAAGATADAAADADAAA TDAAADATAGAAAGAGAAA
TDADAATAAGAAGAAGAA TAAATAAGAAGAAGAA TDDAAAGADTADAAADADAAA TATAAADADAAADA TDAAAAGADTAGAAGA
TDAGGTAAAAAA DAAAAAAAAA DAAAAAA TGGADTAGAAGA TDADTAGAAAGAGA TDAAAAAAAAA DTAGAGAAAGA

I did a lot of thinking on paper in trying to figure how to approach it and yes I understood the algorithm for the 4 possible equations. But I’m just struggling to still understand how to solve these problems and the tricks that can be a pull of in python to complete these codes.

- I tried to approach the string in so many ways. I've ended up using a.split(t) from the main string to create many lists in which all the sequence within t***t would not get append it looked promising since they are all odd index but I always end up with a lot of redundancy and end up failing.
- I also tried to reduce the amount of main function () and regroup more if-else statements but I just keep hitting walls.
- I have tried to solve it while working as string only but nothing... I’m completely at a loss. If anyone could please point me in the right direction with a similar problem, examples, more source material or even fix a part of this code so I can understand better.

At this point, the assignment is over it was due today. I really would appreciate if someone can share how to approach/solve this problem, I would really like to understand exactly how to approach these kinds of problems. Otherwise, I will never fully understand my next assignments and won't be able to spend more time on different class assignments.

Thank you

This code is one of the many I did but this one represent what I was trying to do.

```
def get_E0(x,y):        ###UP
    return x, y+1

def get_E1(x,y):        ###RIGHT
    return x+1, y

def get_E2(x,y):        ###DOWN
    return x, y-1

def get_E3(x,y):        ###LEFT
    return x-1 ,y


def get_DADE0(i,x,y):                     ### Def for every possible left or right turn
    for letters in b[i]:                  ### Trying to work with the sliced list  
        if letters == 'A':                ### For every possible left or right turn                
            x,y = get_E0(x,y)             ### Was hoping to introduce a counter 
            if i % 2 == 0:                ### for each index list in b
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'D':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('D')
            break
    return x,y,b

def get_DADE1(i,x,y):
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E1(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'D':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('D')
            break
    return x,y,b
       
   
def get_DADE2(i,x,y):
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E2(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'D':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('D')
            break
    return x,y,b   
    
     
   
def get_DADE3(i,x,y):
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E3(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'D':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('D')
            break
    return x,y,b                
    

def get_GAGE0(i,x,y):
    
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E0(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'G':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('G')
            break
    return x,y,b                
    

def get_GAGE1(i,x,y):
    
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E1(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'G':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('G')
            break
    return x,y,b    
    
def get_GAGE2(i,x,y):
    
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E2(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'G':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('G')
            break
    return x,y,b    
    

def get_GAGE3(i,x,y):
    
    for letters in b[i]:
        if letters == 'A':
            x,y = get_E3(x,y)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                get_outAppend(outX,outY,x,y)
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('A')
        if letters == 'G':
            b[i] = b[i].lstrip('G')
            break
    return x,y,b     
    

a = str('AAAAADADAAGAAAAAAAGAADADAAAAADAAAAAAAAATDDAAAGATADAAADADAAATDAAADATAGAAAGAGAAATDADAATAAGAAGAAGAATAAATAAGAAGAAGAATDDAAAGADTADAAADADAAATATAAADADAAADATDAAAAGADTAGAAGATDAGGTAAAAAADAAAAAAAAADAAAAAATGGADTAGAAGATDADTAGAAAGAGATDAAAAAAAAADTAGAGAAAGA')

b = a.split('T')
x = 0                                   ### starting values for x,y
y = 0
outX, outY = [0], [0]                   ### List to append coordinates  


while True:                             ### Here I was trying to see if the loops would work as intended
                                        ### 
    x,y,b = get_DADE0(0,x,y)    #up
    x,y,b = get_DADE1(0,x,y)    #right
    x,y,b = get_GAGE2(0,x,y)    #down
    x,y,b = get_GAGE1(0,x,y)    #right
    x,y,b = get_DADE0(0,x,y)    #up
    x,y,b = get_DADE1(0,x,y)    #right
    x,y,b = get_DADE2(0,x,y)    #down
    x,y,b = get_DADE3(0,x,y)    #left
    
    x,y,b = get_DADE0(1,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_DADE1(1,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_GAGE0(1,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_DADE1(1,x,y)
    
    x,y,b = get_DADE2(2,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_DADE3(2,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_DADE0(2,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_DADE1(2,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_GAGE0(2,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_GAGE3(2,x,y)
    x,y,b = get_DADE2(2,x,y) 
    break



    
    
plt.axis('equal')                  ### Plotting my figure.
plt.axis([0,7,0,10])
plt.plot(outX,outY, color = 'r')
```

Comment: Don't destroy questions..It's in the edit history anyway.  Maybe don't do your homework on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I was going to put it back.... but w.e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have put a lot of effort in your assignment. You are asking for hints and tricks how to tackle this kind of problem, so instead of giving you a full solution straight away I would like to provide a possible strategy how to build a solution step-by-step.

Instead of trying to split the string according to whether the pen is up of down beforehand, it's easier to just loop over the whole string and deal with "T" when you encounter them in the string. After all, the only difference between the pen being up or down is whether we should store the current position for drawing or not. This means that the main part of your code will look something like.

```
for command in a:
    # do something with command
```

Here `command` can be either a movement ("A"), a rotation ("G", or "D") or a line toggle ('T'). The first command, "A" will update the position of the turtle depending on its current position and the direction it's moving in, and "G" and "T" will update the direction the turtle is moving in. The toggle command will change whether the pen is up or down. This means that the state of the turtle can be described by three parameters: the current position, `(x,y)`, the direction the turtle is moving in, `(u, v)`, and a boolean to describe if the pen is currently up or down, `is_pen_down`. Initially, the turtle is located at `(0,0)`, and I assume is moving in the positive y-direction, i.e. `(u, v) == (0, 1)`. The pen is initially down. With this in mind, the for-loop becomes

```
x, y = (0, 0)
u, v = (0, 1)
is_pen_down = True
for command in a:
    if command == 'A':
        # move forward
    elif command == 'G':
        # rotate left
    elif command == 'D':
        # rotate right
    elif command == 'T':
        # update pen
```

The next step would be to figure out what the new position and direction of the turtle will be.

According to the assignment, 'A' will move the turtle one step forward. This means that if `(x, y)` is the current position and `(u, v)` the current direction, the new position will be `(x+u, y+v)`. The direction will remain unchanged.

'D' will rotate the turtle 90 degrees to the right. In vector notation this means that the new direction will be `(v, -u)`. The position will stay the same in this case.

Similarly, 'G' will rotate the turtle 90 degrees to the left which means that the new direction will be `(-v, u)`.

Using these expressions, the updated for-loop looks like:

```
x, y = (0, 0)
u, v = (0, 1)
is_pen_down = True
for command in a:
    if command == 'A':
        x += u
        y += v
    elif command == 'G':
        u, v = -v, u
    elif command == 'D':
        u, v = v, -u
    elif command == 'T':
        # update pen
```

What is left is toggling the pen and drawing the lines. For this we need to keep track of the position of the turtle while the pen is down. This can be done by appending the current x- and y-position to separate lists like in your code every time the position of the turtle is updated is the pen is down. If the pen goes up (i.e. when the command is equal to 'T' and `is_pen_down` is True), the line should be drawn and we should start a new line. Also, when the loop is finished we should remember to plot the current line if the pen is still down, and to show the plot. This means that the final program will look something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 'AAAAADADAAGAAAAAAAGAADADAAAAADAAAAAAAAATDDAAAGATADAAADADAAATDAAADATAGAAAGAGAAATDADAATAAGAAGAAGAATAAATAAGAAGAAGAATDDAAAGADTADAAADADAAATATAAADADAAADATDAAAAGADTAGAAGATDAGGTAAAAAADAAAAAAAAADAAAAAATGGADTAGAAGATDADTAGAAAGAGATDAAAAAAAAADTAGAGAAAGA'

x, y = (0, 0)
u, v = (0, 1)
is_pen_down = True
outX = [x]
outY = [y]
for command in a:
    if command == 'A':
        x += u
        y += v
    elif command == 'G':
        u, v = -v, u
    elif command == 'D':
        u, v = v, -u
    elif command == 'T':
        if is_pen_down:
            # pen about to go up
            plt.plot(outX, outY)
            outX = []
            outY = []
        # toggle pen
        is_pen_down = not(is_pen_down)
    if is_pen_down:
        outX.append(x)
        outY.append(y)

# after loop, if pen is down plot open line
if is_pen_down:
    plt.plot(outX, outY)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I must say thanks to you I do understand way better with all the documentation that I've accumulated and where exactly I went off and started to over complicated myself. The  ''  i.e. (u, v) == (0, 1) " really helped me figure it out when and why I started to misunderstood the problem while working it as a string. Thanks you for all the help